# android google maps marker based on string parameter

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I need some help regarding google maps on android. The problem I want to solve is to how to select a marker icon from drawable folder and draw it on google maps based on parameters received via ajax call. Here is what I have tried

```
    String img_name = jsonObj.getString("icon_name")+"_"+jsonObj.getString("icon_state") == "0" ? "on" : "off";
    // img_name will get a value thing like 'cat_on', I have the icon in drawable folder

    // how do I use this img_name in the .icon line below


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title(jsonObj.getString("header"))
        .snippet(jsonObj.getString("title").concat(jsonObj.getString("description")))
        .position(new LatLng(
            Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("lat")),
            Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("lng"))
        ))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.resourceId))
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question exactly, but you can use

[getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

from android Resources to get the id of your icon by the name.

Something like this:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("icon_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

if you call it from an activity for example.

[getResources() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources())

**Update:**

Have you tried this?

```
String img_name = jsonObj.getString("icon_name")+"_"+jsonObj.getString("icon_state") == "0" ? "on" : "off";
    // img_name will get a value thing like 'cat_on', I have the icon in drawable folder

    // how do I use this img_name in the .icon line below
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(img_name, "drawable", getPackageName());

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title(jsonObj.getString("header"))
        .snippet(jsonObj.getString("title").concat(jsonObj.getString("description")))
        .position(new LatLng(
            Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("lat")),
            Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("lng"))
        ))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId))
    );
```

Comment: a new thread is calling the function to draw the markers, I tried this int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(img_name, "drawable", this.getPackageName()); and .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.id.drawableResourceId)) but does not work the .icon line says it does not know drawableResourceId, i have defined just above the mMap.addMarker line. thanks anyways

Comment: yes it works. thanks. anyideas how can I get it such that if user has hdpi screen or xhdpi screen then to choose icons based on that

Comment: never mind found it here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html